# Is there a max amount of time that can pass between a person wishing for something and an ifrit wishcrafter using wishbound arcana?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, sorcerer

I have a player who is playing a [wishcrafter](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-ifrit/wishcrafter-sorcerer-ifrit/) that had gotten a big bad, let's call her V, to wish that another big bad, let's call him B, would be out of the way. B was not anywhere near the party at the time, but will be soon.

Would the wishcrafter be able to use wishbound arcana to grant the wish of V when they encounter B later?

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be left up to GM discretion, but I would lean toward allowing it to be used for 24 hours, based on these excerpts from the ability:

> A creature can make a wish as a free action *at any time*...
>   ...cannot use this ability to grant that creature any further wishes for 24 hours.

A more stringent application of the rules would require it to be said within the same round of combat (within 6s) since it is acting as the verbal component of the spell... something that is typically supplied concurrently with the spell being cast.

Answer (score 0):

**Wishbound Arcana** says:

> At 1st level, the wishcrafter can use the wishes of non-genie creatures other than herself **in place of the normal verbal components of her spells**... A wishcrafter gains a +1 bonus to her caster level when **using a creature's wish as a verbal component** in this manner, but cannot include herself as a target of such spells.

Strictly by RAW, the time limit is "the same turn" (less even than "the same round"). The wishcrafter is using the wish as a verbal component of the spell, and verbal components have to be provided as the spell is cast; you can't speak a spell's verbal components in the morning and cast the spell silently later that day. Some spells that could be used to "grant" V's wish in the same turn would be:

- *silent image* or a similar illusion spell (producing paperwork showing B's out-of-the-way-ness);
- *teleport* or *greater teleport* (to take the party to B);
- *modify memory* (to make V think B is out of the way [normally only usable by bards and a few clerics]);

However, it certainly seems like a thematic and fun house rule to make the time limit be "until the wishcrafter has an opportunity to grant the creature's wish."

Comment: That's RAW. that's your interpretation of the rules. -1

Comment: Can you provide a reference that contradicts me?

Comment: The ability specifically uses 'Free Action during the Wishcrafter's turn' as 'one example', implying that it's not mandatory for the Wish to happen during the Wishcrafter's turn... and I think you're misinterpreting OP's intent with your suggestions; I don't think they want to *show* B that V wants B out of the way, but to get a boost when the party goes to confront B.

Comment: It's not mandatory for the wish to happen during the wishcrafter's turn, because sometimes spells can be cast on other people's turns (*feather fall*, readied actions).  This doesn't override the fact that a spell's verbal components have to be supplied while the spell is being cast, not earlier or later.  My examples are the only part that's opinion-based, and I was listing the kinds of spells I think the archetype expects you to use this ability for.

Comment: @PlutoThePlanet Are you saying that in order for a wishcrafter to grant a wish spoken during someone else's turn the spell cast must have a casting time of immediate or have been readied prior that has a casting time of less than one round?

Comment: @jneko Strictly by RAW, yes.  Nothing in the wishcrafter's toolbox lets them use verbal components now to cast a spell later.  But as always, the GM is free to houserule otherwise.